# jquery + Ajax - focusout sending multiple requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I have a form where is about 20 input[text] fields.
What I am trying to do is as soon as you move from one field to the other it will trigger an ajax request.

everything is working fine but there is a strange behaviour

When I move from one field to do other it will send a same request multiple times.

so in debugger I see something like

```
Request URL:http://xxxxxxx.com/ajax/loadInformation.php?autoSave=1&rowid=35139&name=FieldName&value=asd&_=1454334363440
Request URL:http://xxxxxxx.com/ajax/loadInformation.php?autoSave=1&rowid=35139&name=FieldName&value=asd&_=1454334363440
```

I am expecting always just one request but it is not consistent. Sometimes it will send 2 same request other time its 4 same requests?

I am encountering this issue in Chrome and IE11 but didnt check other browsers.

```
$(function() {   
     $("input").focusin(function() {
        var rowid = $("input[name=RowID]").val();
        var oldValue = $(this).val();
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        $(this).focusout(function () {
               var newValue = $(this).val();
               $.get('ajax/loadInformation.php',{autoSave: "1", rowid: rowid, name: name, value: newValue,_:$.now()});
            }
        }); 
     });
});
```

Comment: You are nesting event binding, that's why... Each time you focus an element, you are adding a new focusout event. Use instead: `$("input").focusin(function() {...}).focusout(function(){...});`  and use `$.fn.data()` to set relevant new and old values even i don't see what would be the use of these varaibles... In fact, just looks like you should bind focusout event, and no focusin

Comment: What @A.Wolff says is right, if you're not using the var oldValue you're getting during focusin then you don't need to bind anything to focusin at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, nesting handlers. Anyway, just bind `focusout` event:

```
$(function() {
  $("input").change(function() {
      var rowid = $("input[name=RowID]").val();
      var name = $(this).attr("name");
      var newValue = $(this).val();
      $.get('ajax/loadInformation.php', {
        autoSave: "1",
        rowid: rowid,
        name: name,
        value: newValue,
        _: $.now()
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And now not sure why you just don't use `change` event if you need to compare `oldValue` to new one. `change` would be fired on input blur only if value has changed.

Comment: This seems to fixed it however what If I need to send request only if oldValue!=newValue

I am lame in jquery but I thought that focusin will select oldValue from field and then when I move from the same field I will have newValue so I can compare them on focusout

Comment: For just value changed, use `change` instead of `focusout`

Comment: @A.Wolff - I facing exact similar issue with nesting of `.('focusin')` and `.on('focusout)`. Only that in my case I am using the `.on('focusin')` event to get the row number (of the `td`s) to dynamically create **IDs** and then use these **IDs** to trigger `.on('focusout')` events to get the field (`td`) values and trigger addition of new rows. The first row works just fine. From next cycle onwards it keeps increasing the number of new rows being added. **What could I do to stop this behavior?**

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `GET` request gets triggered twice or more is because every time you `focusin` on an `<input>` you're binding the `focusout` event *again*. A possible solution would be using [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) on your `focusout` event:

```
$(function(){   
  $("input").focusin(function(){
    var rowid = $("input[name=RowID]").val();
    var oldValue = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    $(this).one('focusout', function(){ // <--- using .one()
      var newValue = $(this).val();

      $.get('ajax/loadInformation.php',{autoSave: "1", rowid: rowid, name: name, value: newValue,_:$.now()});

    }); 
 });
});
```

Comment: And just looks like `focusin` event is complelty useless regarding expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff that's probably true and my first thoughts exactly. But maybe `oldValue` and `newValue` need to be compared within the `focusout` handler at some point

Comment: Ya i just was guessing about it. So just looks like OP should use `change` event

Answer (score -2):

You need to check whether there is any AJAX call is already in-progress. This can be done as follows.

```
    $(function() {   
             var isAjaxCallInProgress = false;

             $("input").focusin(function() {
                var rowid = $("input[name=RowID]").val();
                var oldValue = $(this).val();
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                $(this).focusout(function () {
                  if(isAjaxCallInProgress) return;
                  isAjaxCallInProgress = true;
                  var newValue = $(this).val();
                      $.ajax({
                         url: 'ajax/loadInformation.php',
                         data: {
                           autoSave: "1", 
                           rowid: rowid, 
                           name: name, 
                           value: newValue,_:$.now()
                         },
                         success: function(data) {
                             isAjaxCallInProgress = false;
                         },
                         type: 'GET'
                       });                                    
                }); 
             });
        });
```

Comment: This will prevent the code from sending multiple `GET` requests. However, it does not fix the core issue: `focusout`gets triggered to often. Also, if a request fails in your example, `isAjaxCallInProgress` will stay `true`.